# Does TP-LINK WN822N work on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek, atheros, realtek-wireless

I plan to install Ubuntu soon on my PC. I currently use a TP-LINK TL-WN822N wireless adapter. I want to know if it will work without additional setup.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have a TP-link wireless adapter (Model: TL-WN725N). It doesn't work very well at all with AES encryption, but it works fine out of the box with TKIP encryption (in Xubuntu), although the antenna (or lack thereof) isn't great.

Answer (score 20):

It should work with Ubuntu without additional setup. But kernel driver for this adapter may work unstable. I suggest to install a better driver from source.

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

This answer is applicable to hardware version 3.0 of this adapter with a Realtek chip. Previous versions should work well out of the box.

I packaged this driver to DKMS format and added it to ppa. If you instal it from there, you will not need to re-install it after kernel upgrades. It can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

Comment: Basically: you need to access the internet to install the drivers to access the internet. Congratulations: we have a chicken and egg problem! But now, speaking seriously, that git seems like a great source of drivers, updated quite a lot.

Comment: The dongle will work out of the box, but not great.

Comment: I am trying to add a monitor interface on top of this device in Ubuntu 16.04 but iw does not even see it. Any tips? Otherwise, it connects to an AP and seems to work.

Comment: Oops: "E: Unable to locate package rtl8192cu-dkms" ... any idea why this might be? NB this is not straight Ubuntu, but Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.3 (meant to be a fork of Ubuntu)

Comment: I get "E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
" for 'sudo apt-get update', this is probably the reason the commenter above me gets 'unable to locate package'.

Comment: According to readme in repository, it has been deprecated in favour of `rtl8xxxu ` (which I do not know how to install, by the way)

Comment: @ccamara The `rtl8xxxu` is in the kernel, you don't need to install anything. But it doesn't support all devices and may work not well.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsTP-Link

Look for TL-WN822N

---

[image: TL-WN822N]

Please ensure that you also install linux-firmware package after installing Ubuntu.

If you still have issues please post results of lspci and lsusb commands.

Comment: Linux-firmware is not needed, lspci is irrelevant, but good hardware version information.

Comment: This worked great for my TL-WN823N, too.

Answer (score 5):

There are 4 different versions of this wireless adapter and they use different chipsets:

- Versions 1 and 2 use Atheros AR7010.
- Version 3 uses Realtek RTL8192CU.
- Version 4 uses Realtek RTL8192EU.

To find out which version you have, take a look at the back of the adapter - it will say something like "Ver:3.0". Alternatively, use `lsusb` - my TP-LINK WN822N V3 identifies as "Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter".

---

If you have the Atheros-based one, the driver used is [ath9k_htc](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath9k_htc) and it should work out-of-the-box.

[This page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/rtl819x) lists the drivers currently used for Realtek chipsets - essentially, they will all be replaced with `rtl8xxxu` at some point.

That said, while version 3 works out-of-the-box with the `rtl8192cu` driver, that driver is *really bad* (slow speed, disconnects occasionally). You'll want to install [rtl8192cu-fixes](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) to make it usable (which will also blacklist `rtl8192cu`).

I have no information about version 4, but RTL8192EU should work out-of-the-box with the `rtl8xxxu` driver on newer distros.

Comment: From what I understood from this and previous answers, if I have v3 I should use `rtl8xxxu`, since `ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi` does no longer work and `https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes` states that it is obsolote in favour of newest `rtl8xxxu`. Unfortunately, I do not get any clue on how to install that driver. Could you give more details, please?

Comment: For Version 4, (RTL81EU) you can install the driver from:
https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux
Without this driver I've much problems with very slow connections.